# onJoin event not replacing lastPlayer

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to make a command that welcomes a recently joined player back, however the join listener doesn't replace the lastPlayer variable so when you type /welba it just says null.

```java
package me.spoonle.welba.command;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

import me.spoonle.welba.Main;
import me.spoonle.welba.Utils.Utils;

public class WelbaCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    private Main plugin;

    public WelbaCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;

        plugin.getCommand("welba").setExecutor(this);
    }

    public static String lastPlayer = null;

    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        lastPlayer = e.getPlayer().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(Utils.chat("&cYou don't have access to this command! Only players can use this command!"));
            return true;
        }

        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (p.hasPermission("welba.use")) {
            p.chat("Welcome Back, " + lastPlayer);
        } else {
            p.sendMessage("&cYou don't have use to this command!");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Theres my code for the plugin. Do I need to change where the listener is? I tried making a separate class for it but when I called lastPlayer in my Main class, it wouldn't pick up the variable.

Comment: I have no idea what am I talking about, but you might forgot to register events, with something like this: `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);`

Comment: I have that in my Main class already @alx

Comment: Then your main class is going to receive events, and this one won't. They both need that if they're both supposed to receive events.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `Listener` Interface and register the class in your main class.

Registering your `Listener` class in your `Main.java`:

```java
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListener(), this);       
    }
}
```

And Implement the Listener in `MyListener.java`:

```java
public class MyListener implements org.bukkit.event.Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        // implement your handling ...
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("§cIt works!");
    }
}
```

For further Information see See [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/) for more informations.